# How do i have a custom callback upon close using MicroModal?

Tags: javascript

im using [MicroModal](https://micromodal.now.sh/#usage) to display a modal window.
Everything works fine, except during the closing of the modal, i want to call an event to do something. I just don't get it where to do the callback.

This is the init code :

```
        MicroModal.init({
        onShow: modal => console.info(`${modal.id} is shown`), 
        onClose: modal => console.info(`${modal.id} is 
        hidden`),  
        openTigger : 'data-micromodal-trigger',
        closeTrigger: 'data-micromodal-close',
        disableScroll: true,
        disableFocus: false,
        awaitCloseAnimation: false,
        debugMode: true,                
      });
```

I even tried modifying the onClose property to call my event, but it wouldnt execute. i.e.:

```
onClose: callMyEvent,
```

Anyone that has previously used this library can give me some hints on how to do this pls?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of calling init, I called the show method with the optional object and that solved it.

```
MicroModal.show('modal-id',{
   onClose: myCustomEvent
 });
```